# Best approach on kafka/confluent platform: "Stream S3 files -> process in java app -> store in Oracle DB"

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers

I am pretty new to Kafka world. We have a requirement that bunch of files (protobuf format) from Amazon S3 has to be processed and dumped into Oracle DB. So we want use Kafka/Confluent platform. Below is the approach i have been thinking of,

1. Build Java app to pull files from S3 using Amazon SDK(Since S3 Source connector licensed, so sake of POC we will be using java app)

   **NOTE:** Here we may get more files, so we may end up creating batch app which will be trigger by java app
2. Process data and produce kafka messages
3. Store in DB using DB Sink connector

Can somebody please share your opinions and suggestions?

Comment: Apache Spark, Flink or Nifi or just plain Java would work fine. What issues are you having?

Comment: I dont have any issues right now, but trying to finalize the approach. Do you think this approach is good?

Comment: I'm not going to say if it's good or not. Either you can directly write the code or use a higher level framework written by someone else and fit the components together

Comment: Going with this approach will be a good option, as the connectors are built so that they can ease your work. The approach looks quite clear and transparent to me.